# Adding javascript and a webpart to page using app model

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I want to create an app that will add some javascript and a web part to a page in SharePoint.

The page is a list page and already exists (AllItems.aspx page in the document library). I just want to add some js and a web part to it.

I am using SharePoint 2013 (i want to make this reusable so it has to be an app).

Is this possible using the app model and if so are there any tutorials?

Comment: Why does it have to be an app? Apps are not the only way to make things reusable.  Templates are meant to be reusable, as @Keerthi's answer displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly,

Add the web part under **edit page** and also add the required js using the JS link.

Now go to list settings -> Save list as template.

The list will be now be saved as a template and it can be added under existing apps section.

Comment: I already have an app that provisions content types and lists. IDeally i just want something in this app where i can say add this snippet of js onto the AllItems.aspx page.  This way every time this app is added to a site collection it will do it.

Comment: You can add the js file in the web part, export it and add it wherever necessary. Check this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8a9b856-9eea-4c8e-bc80-30e1a30c2294/how-to-save-a-webpart-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013-foundation?forum=sharepointgeneral